# Find and display max and min values from a string of numbers

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the max value and min value from a given string in c# but I get wrong output could you please help?

```
namespace ConsoleApp8
{

  class Program
  {

    public static class Kata
    {
      public static string HighAndLow(string numbers)
      {
        int max = numbers.Max();
        int min = numbers.Min();
        return max + " " + min;
      }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(Kata.HighAndLow("1 2 3 4 5"));
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

  }

}
```

My output is 53 32 how could I fix this?

Comment: I can't see how you would get that output with your code. Unless you somehow extend the `string` type, there is no `String.Max` function in C#.

Comment: @CeeMcSharpface `string` is `IEnumerable<char>`

Comment: in this case, `using System.Linq` would be required. It would take the space chars into account and certainly not do what OP might think it would.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do Katas without help? This can and should be considered cheating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first slipt the string and then find the min and max.

For example from your code having numbers separated by spaces:

```
public static string HighAndLow(string numbers)
{
  var list = numbers.Split(' ').ToList();
  var max = list.Max();
  var min = list.Min();
  return max + " " + min;
}
```

But here we compare chars (as in your code) and we need to convert to numbers:

```
public static string HighAndLow(string numbers)
{
  var list = numbers.Split(' ').ToList();
  var max = list.Select(int.Parse).Max();
  var min = list.Select(int.Parse).Min();
  return max + " " + min;
}
```

Also we assume that there is only numbers without checking errors with `Parse` in case of there are others things than numbers... so we can write for example:

```
public static string HighAndLow(string numbers)
{
  var list = numbers.Split(' ').Select(s => int.TryParse(s, out int value) ? value : 0);
  return list.Max() + " " + list.Min();
}
```

But that raises the question of what to do if there is a conversion error, return 0?

Comment: it applies alphanumeric order and not by integer value, "2" will be bigger than "10"

Comment: I wouldn't answer this because solving a programming excercise for others doesn't teach them anything. However, you could improve this by computing `.Select(int.Parse)` only once on the list definition